# Insert comma into varchar substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I would like to split a string by a comma and space.  I am using SQL Server.
Not sure if I should use charindex/String_Split/etc.

```
    SELECT  HCPCS,
            LEFT(HCPCS,5) as "CPT",                 
            SUBSTRING(HCPCS,6,8) as "MOD"                               

    FROM    MyTable
```

**Output**

```
 HCPCS        CPT        MOD
 99214POTC    99214      POTC
```

**Desired Output**

```
HCPCS         CPT        MOD
99214POTC     99214      PO, TC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use STUFF to place a comma inside a string.

```
Select STUFF('Test',3, 0,', ')
```

in your case it might be

```
Select STUFF(SUBSTRING(HCPCS,6,8), 3, 0, ', ')
```

Comment: So Easy...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using concatenation operator (+) in SQL. Below code will give expected result. You must be misunderstood the SUBSTRING function, the third parameter of the SUBSTRING function represents length not the position.

`select HCPCS, LEFT(HCPCS,5) as "CPT", SUBSTRING(HCPCS,6,2) + ',' + SUBSTRING(HCPCS,8,2) as "MOD";`

Hope this helps.